# Golang xml.Unmarshal interface types

Tags: xml, go

Using the `xml` package in golang I'm having trouble unmarshalling a list of non-homogenous types.  Consider the following XML document whose nested elements are a list of non-homogenous types:

```xml
<mydoc>
  <foo>Foo</foo>
  <bar>Bar</bar>
  <foo>Another Foo</foo>
  <foo>Foo #3</foo>
  <bar>Bar 2</bar>
</mydoc>
```

And the following golang code to test XML un/marshalling (also here on [the go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/aG3IglaI9w)):

```go
package main

import "encoding/xml"
import "fmt"

const sampleXml = `
<mydoc>
  <foo>Foo</foo>
  <bar>Bar</bar>
  <foo>Another Foo</foo>
  <foo>Foo #3</foo>
  <bar>Bar 2</bar>
</mydoc>
`

type MyDoc struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"mydoc"`
  Items   []Item
}

type Item interface {
  IsItem()
}

type Foo struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"foo"`
  Name    string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (f Foo) IsItem() {}

type Bar struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"bar"`
  Nombre  string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (b Bar) IsItem() {}

func main() {
  doMarshal()
  doUnmarshal()
}

func doMarshal() {
  myDoc := MyDoc{
    Items: []Item{
      Foo{Name: "Foo"},
      Bar{Nombre: "Bar"},
      Foo{Name: "Another Foo"},
      Foo{Name: "Foo #3"},
      Bar{Nombre: "Bar 2"},
    },
  }
  bytes, err := xml.MarshalIndent(myDoc, "", "  ")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  // Prints an XML document just like "sampleXml" above.
  println(string(bytes))
}

func doUnmarshal() {
  myDoc := MyDoc{}
  err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(sampleXml), &myDoc)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  // Fails to unmarshal the "Item" elements into their respective structs.
  fmt.Printf("ERR: %#v", myDoc)
}
```

You'll see that `doMarshal()` produces the exact XML document I expect; however, `doUnmarshal()` fails to deserialize the "Item" elements into their respective structs.  I've tried a few changes but nothing seems to get them to unmarshal properly (creating storage for `myDoc.Items`, changing the type of "Items" to `[]*Item` [and others], fiddling with the XML tags, etc).

Any ideas how to get `xml.Unmarshal(...)` to deserialize a list of elements of unrelated types?

Comment: If a field is an interface, the decoder has no way of telling what actual type to use. I don't recall if this works, but try building a struct with initialized interface values.

Comment: @JimB: ah yes, that makes perfect sense - the decoder couldn't possibly know which type to use.  I suppose that's the general problem I'm facing. Perhaps I just need to use a decoder directly and map element names to known types.

Comment: Also more general: Go interfaces are about behaviour (methods only, not properties), not data. So i would consider it a miss-use of go's idea of interfaces.

Comment: I'd personally avoid this because I dislike so much obfuscation but if you really want a working `xml.Unmarshal` for your interfaces you could implement `Unmarshaller`. It would be pretty straight forward, figure out the type based on the XML elements, create a new instance of that type, unmarshal into that with the default unmarshaller, assign that to the interface field of your struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by other comments, the decoder cannot deal with interface fields without some help. Implementing `xml.Unmarshaller` on the container will make it do what you want (full working example on the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FRzdAFrXZ1)):

```
func (md *MyDoc) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    md.XMLName = start.Name
    // grab any other attrs

    // decode inner elements
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        var i Item
        switch tt := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            switch tt.Name.Local {
            case "foo":
                i = new(Foo) // the decoded item will be a *Foo, not Foo!
            case "bar":
                i = new(Bar)
                // default: ignored for brevity
            }
            // known child element found, decode it
            if i != nil {
                err = d.DecodeElement(i, &tt)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                md.Items = append(md.Items, i)
                i = nil
            }
        case xml.EndElement:
            if tt == start.End() {
                return nil
            }
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

This is just an implementation of what @evanmcdonnal suggests. All this does is instantiate the proper `Item` based on the name of the next Token, then call `d.DecodeElement()` with it (i.e. let the xml decoder do the heavy lifting).

Note that the unmarshalled `Items` are pointers. You'll need to do some more work if you want values. This also needs to be expanded some more for proper  handling of errors or unexpected input data.