# How to Unmarshaling dynamic XML in GO

Tags: xml, go

I try to parse XML using Go, which is used to exchange data with another system. I am aware how parsing with the xml.Unmarshal function works in principle. However, in the protocol the child element of the root element `<PROTO>` vary (see the examples below). For the child elements (`REQUEST.DATA`, `REQUEST.ACL`, `REQUEST.NAC`, ... - far more than twenty different) I have defined structs with `xml:...`-syntax so far - the parsing of these single child elements works.

But, is there a nice way to parse the whole message as a struct, where one varible type depends on the child element? For example with using an interface?

Example of possible XML messages:

```xml
<PROTO
   version="1.00">
  <REQUEST.DATA>
    <DATA-L>Some information</DATA-L>
  </REQUEST.DATA>
</PROTO>
```

```xml
<PROTO
   version="1.00">
  <REQUEST.ACK>
    <ACK-ID>1</ACK-ID>
  <REQUEST.ACK>
</PROTO>
```

Snippets from my Go application:

```golang
// XML: REQUEST.DATA
type DataRequest struct {
    LData string `xml:"DATA-L"`
}

// XML: REQUEST.ACK
type AckRequest struct {
    AckId int `xml:"ACK-ID"`
}

// XML: PROTO  <============= ??
type Request struct {
    Version float32  `xml:"version,attr"`
    RemoteRequest {AckRequest, DataRequest, ...} ????
}

func main() {
    message := `<PROTO version="1.00"><REQUEST.ACK><ACK-ID>1</ACK-ID><REQUEST.ACK></PROTO>`
    data := `<REQUEST.ACK><ACK-ID>1</ACK-ID><REQUEST.ACK>`
    doc := &AckRequest{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &doc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("data %+v", doc)
}
```

Instead of just parsing the child element `data` I want to parse the whole document `message` (`<PROTO>` involved). And want have a structure that contains the information of the respective child element.

Comment: Have you tried putting AckRequest and DataRequest in the struct at same level as Version?  I the the Unmarshal will just fill in the ones that are there leaving the other zero (or if you use pointers to the structs they are left as nil pointers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works in principle, but then I have to add all sorts of possible child elements at the level of `Version` (in real far more than 20) and when using the struct i need to querie every single one to find out which child element was present. Is there no better way? :(

Comment: There is. You can define the proper `UnmarshalXML` method on your outer tupe, `Request`—to make it satisfy the [`Unmarshaler` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler), and in it, use the lower-level `Decoder` interface to read the XML by tokens and dynamically switch processing based on the opening tag of a contained element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the `DataRequest` and `AckRequest` as pointers in the `Request` struct. This way you can check later if they are `nil` or not.

```
// XML: REQUEST.DATA
type DataRequest struct {
    LData string `xml:"DATA-L"`
}

// XML: REQUEST.ACK
type AckRequest struct {
    AckId int `xml:"ACK-ID"`
}

type Request struct {
    Version float32      `xml:"version,attr"`
    Ack     *AckRequest  `xml:"REQUEST.ACK"`
    Data    *DataRequest `xml:"REQUEST.DATA"`
}

func main() {
    message := `<PROTO version="1.00"><REQUEST.ACK><ACK-ID>1</ACK-ID></REQUEST.ACK></PROTO>`
    proto := &Request{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &proto)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    // if proto.Ack == nil {
    //   fmt.Println("Ack is nil")
    // }
    fmt.Printf("data %+v\n", proto)
    fmt.Printf("data %+v\n", proto.Ack)
}
```

> data &{Version:1 Ack:0xc0000b6050 Data:}
>
> data &{AckId:1}

You can also implement your own decoder and do dynamic type switching https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517875/1199408.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works in principle, however, as written above, instead of the two possible child elements  (`DataRequest` and `AckRequest`), I actually have well over 20. With this suggestions I have to add all sorts of possible child elements as variables to the `Request` struct and when using the struct i need to querie every single variable to find out which child element was present.